# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, comparator

I'm getting this exception when trying to peek an object from an `ArrayList` based on the min value of an attribute.

Here is a snapchatCode from my program:

```
return individuals.stream()
                .parallel()
                .filter(s -> s.getFitness() != fittest.getFitness())
                .min(Comparator.comparingInt(object -> object.getFitness()))
                .get();
```

individuals is an `ArrayList<Individual>`.

```
class Individual{
        int fitness;
        public int getFitness() {
            return fitness;
        }
    }
```

The exception i'm getting on the `get()` method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value
 present
```

After debugging my program i found that all the individuals of the stream have the same fitness value, so after the filter operation no individual is found, so hen we call the `get()` we have an `exception`.

How can I manage to get a random value in the case where all the individual have the same fitness value.

Comment: There is something called `optional`.

Comment: A random value, would that mean a newly constructed `Individual` object with random content? Or?

Comment: `.filter(s -> s.getFitness() <= fittest.getFitness())` ? ...or even`!s.equals(fittest)`...

Comment: Random number for what? Let's say you have `Individual@1{fintess=1}` and `Individual@2{fintess=1}`, which one should receive a new random number?

Comment: Use `Optional.orElse(defaultValue)`

Comment: @OleV.V. I mean a random individual from the list of individduals, as all the individuals has the same fitness value.

Comment: @xerx593 your first proposition worked fine.